# Set GraphView column width

Tags: android-graphview

I'm trying to use the GraphView library. I'm finding it disturbingly difficult to get the same size on all columns with static labels on these columns. The columns to the far right and far left are are just half visible.

I've been trying for so long now, please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes this happens when the viewport is exactly as big as the data. the bars are centered and so the left side of the first and the right side of the last bar will be invisible.

you could set a manual x-viewport which is a little bigger then the data. then you will see it complete

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine. I also used dataSeries.setSpacing(40) to make the columns thinner.

Is it possible to adjust my static horizontal labels so that they appear right under the graphs? One label per column that is.

I see that StaticLabelsFormatter has a setViewPort method, but it looks like this should not be called explicitly?